# Squid Access Log for Particular IP at a particular time

Tags: 14.04, squid

I have used

```
grep 192.168.1.20 /var/log/squid/access.log.1 | awk '{print$3 " " $1" " $8 " " $7}'
```

This is working properly.

But when I want to see the Output for a range of time (18 July 2016) 11-17 time period.

```
grep 192.168.1.20 /var/log/squid/access.log | awk '{print $3 " " $1" " $7}' | awk '$1" "$2>="2016-07-18 11:00" && $1" "$2 
grep 192.168.1.20 /var/log/squid/access.log|grep -E '2016-07-18 (11:00:00-17:00)'| awk '{print $1,$3,$7}'
```

It didn't worked for Me.

Want the command to get the logs for a particular ip at a particular time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer.

```
cat /home/deployer/Downloads/squid_access_log_2_july_2016_13_00-13_59.log | awk '$4 >= "[02/Jul/2016:13:40:00" && $4 < "[02/Jul/2016:13:40:54"'| grep 192.168.1.158
```

It worked for Me.

Hope it will be useful for others.